# Different behavior of direct and copy initialization on MS VC++ (using user-defined conversion operators)

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17, conversion-operator

The following code [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/-ARWs4) with both *g++ 9.1* and *clang 8.0.0* (compilation flags are `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`), but not with *MSVC 19.22* (compilation flags are `/std:c++17 /permissive-`):

```
struct X{};

struct Bar
{
    Bar() = default;

    Bar(X){}
};

struct Foo
{
    operator X() const
    {
        return X{};
    }

    operator Bar() const
    {
        return Bar{};
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    [[maybe_unused]]Bar b1 = foo; // OK
    [[maybe_unused]]Bar b2(foo);  // failed
}
```

*MSVC* compilation errors:

```
<source>(27): error C2668: 'Bar::Bar': ambiguous call to overloaded function
<source>(8): note: could be 'Bar::Bar(Bar &&)'
<source>(7): note: or       'Bar::Bar(X)'
<source>(27): note: while trying to match the argument list '(Foo)'
```

Is it a bug in *MSVC*?

Comment: Over at [RexTester](https://rextester.com/NZZMM41358), I also got `note: or 'Bar::Bar(const Bar &)'`, which makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @PaulSanders Rextester uses an old version of *MSVC* (provided together with *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015*), in godbolt that I have used *MSVC 19.22* (provided together with the latest *MSVS 2019 version 16.2*) is available.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is basically a manifestation of [CWG 2327](https://wg21.link/cwg2327), which dealt with this example:

```
struct Cat {};
struct Dog { operator Cat(); };

Dog d;
Cat c(d);
```

The crux of the issue was that we don't allow for guaranteed copy elision in this case - because we go through `Cat`'s move constructor rather than just initializing via `Dog::operator Cat()` directly.

And it seems like gcc and clang both already implement the *intent* of the issue - which is to do overload resolution on both the constructors and conversion functions at the same time.

In your example:

```
Bar b2(foo);
```

Per the letter of the standard, we consider constructors (and [only constructors](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2.sentence-2)) - which are `Bar(X)`, `Bar(Bar const&)`, and `Bar(Bar&&)`. All three of those are viable, the first by way of `Foo::operator X() const` and the second and third by way of `Foo::operator Bar() const`. We can prefer `Bar(Bar&&)` to `Bar(Bar const&)` but we have way of disambiguating between `Bar(X)` and `Bar(Bar&&)`. MSVC is following the standard in correctly rejecting this initialization. It is not a bug.

But the spirit of CWG 2327 is that this should invoke `Foo::operator Bar() const` directly, which is what gcc and clang do. It is hard to say that this is a bug on their side either since that's probably the behavior we actually want to happen, and will likely be the way it is specified at some point in the future.

Comment: Call this an extension then for gcc and clang?

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe? I think of extensions as like.. things that definitely aren't in the language that compilers added anyway. Like... expression-statements are certainly an extension. This is more like, a pre-interpretation of a core language issue? It's a bit fuzzy.